# Transfer Ubuntu server 10.04 to another 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, transfer, ubuntu-13.04

I am totally new to Linux administration and now I have big problem. I have an old server with some sites, databases, programs etc.. that is Ubuntu 10.04.Because of too much users ,I rented new ,better and faster server but with Ubuntu 13.04.

So , my question is: Does anyone know an easy way to transfer all server data, sites, databases, mail server etc.. from my old machine to new Ubuntu 13.04 server?

P.S: My hosting provider only does IP changes ,they don't provide software support to migrate all my data to new server.

Comment: You don't provide much information. Are you looking to migrate LAMP?

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty depends entirely on how customized your services are.

You will have to install and configure all the services present on your 10.04 box on the new one, and then move over the content/data. This is not something your provider should do for you.

Start by identifying the services you rely on, and do some research on how to install and configure each of them. Each service will have content and configuration, so once you've looked into it, you can probably copy over many of your config files once you have identified them. You will also have to identify where your services store their content, so that you know what to copy from the old server, and where to put it on the new one.
Some learning will be required.